# exporting data from excel to mysql

Tags: mysql, jsp

I have an excel sheet.Using its information I have to derive some details and store it in a mysql table.

my code is:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@page import="java.io.IOException"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.SQLException"%>
<%@page import="cnn.sem_year_conversion"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Iterator"%>
<%@page import="java.io.FileInputStream"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page import="cnn.cn"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>

 <%  
     try
     {
 Connection con=cn.getcon();  
 PreparedStatement ps=null;  

  String name,f_name,branch="",enroll,status="regular",sem,elligible="";
 int year= 0;
 int flag;
 int count=0;
         con.setAutoCommit(false);
        PreparedStatement pstm = null ;
        FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/intel/Documents/student_excel.xls");
        POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem( input ); //creating a new poi reference to the given excel file
        HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);
        HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        Row row;
                 for(int i=1; i<=sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++)
                 { 
                     //points to the starting of excel i.e excel first row
           row = (Row) sheet.getRow(i);  //sheet number
                              if( row.getCell(1)==null) { enroll = "0";}  //suppose excel cell is empty then its set to 0 the variable
                   else enroll = row.getCell(1).toString();   //else copies cell data to name variable

                                  if( row.getCell(2)==null) { name = "0";}  //suppose excel cell is empty then its set to 0 the variable
                   else name = row.getCell(2).toString();   //else copies cell data to name variable

                                      if( row.getCell(3)==null) { f_name = "0";}  //suppose excel cell is empty then its set to 0 the variable
                   else f_name = row.getCell(3).toString();   //else copies cell data to name variable

    if( row.getCell(5)==null) { sem = "0";}  //suppose excel cell is empty then its set to 0 the variable
                   else sem = row.getCell(5).toString();   //else copies cell data to name variable

                switch (sem) {
            case "1":
            case "2":
                year=1;
                break;
            case "3":
            case "4":
                year=2;
                break;
            case "5":
            case "6":
                year=3;
                break;
            case "7":
            case "8":   
                year=4;
                break;
                default:year=0;
        }

      if( row.getCell(6)==null) { elligible="0";}  //suppose excel cell is empty then its set to 0 the variable
                   else elligible = row.getCell(6).toString();   //else copies cell data to elligible variable
if(elligible=="Submitted to RGPV"|| elligible=="Forwarded by RGPV" )
    flag=0;
else
    flag=1;
   if(enroll.contains("AU"))
       branch="au";
   else if(enroll.contains("EC"))
       branch="ec";
   else if(enroll.contains("CS"))
       branch="cs";
   else if(enroll.contains("CE"))
       branch="ce";
   else if(enroll.contains("IT"))
       branch="it";


 String query="insert into student values(?,?,0,3,?,?,?)";  
 ps=con.prepareStatement(query); 
 ps.setString(1, enroll);
 ps.setString(2, name);
 ps.setString(3, branch);
 ps.setInt(4,year);
 ps.setString(5, f_name);
 ps.setString(6, status);


 count=ps.executeUpdate();

                 }


 //For checking data is inserted or not?  

          con.commit();
        pstm.close();
        con.close();
        input.close();
        if(count>0)
        System.out.println("Successful import of excel to mysql table");

        else
          System.out.println("Import Failed.");

    }

     catch(SQLException ex){
       out.println(ex);
    }catch(IOException ioe)`{
       out.println(ioe);
    }


%>

    </body>
</html>
```

But it is generating following error---

```
HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error

type Exception report

messageInternal Server Error

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation for JSP

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
source value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
target value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 32 in the jsp file: /student_info.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
strings in switch are not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable strings in switch)

note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.0 logs.
GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.0
```

I have used String in switch case because on using int it was giving exception-

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1.0"
```

How to solve this?

Comment: What did you try to fix this error?

Comment: I didn't understood the error so i was unable to solve it

Comment: Is this error from your current code? Which line? Full error stack trace?What was the error with the "int" version? Which jdk are you using?

Comment: Yes this error is from my current code. Its generating from the switch case. The second error i have mentioned is due t int. I am using jdk1.6

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be the exception of switch statement because A switch works with the byte, short, char, and int primitive data types.

Try to convert the data to integer first before you going to switch it.

Comment: I tried it already but then it was giving the exception i have mentioned above  "NumberFormatexception"

Comment: The NumberFormatexception occur when string to float conversion is required. So i first converted string variable to float and then to int. And used the int version in switch case. Now the code is running properly.